# What are the dimensions of a box that can contain 20 arrows?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, ammunition

I am playing a level 13 Fighter with the Sharpshooter martial archetype (from [Unearthed Arcana: Fighter](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/2016_Fighter_UA_1205_1.pdf)). I took the Sharpshooter feat as well, of course, and the Archery fighting style. I shoot between 3 and 6 arrows per round (using Action Surge and Extra Attack), so I need a lot of arrows to keep me going through combat.

A [Bag of Holding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bag-of-holding) seems to be best option for holding the arrows I will need; since I read [this thread](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103564/sharp-objects-in-a-bag-of-holding), I plan on using a box to hold the bundles - presumably 1 box per bundle to keep things organized.

**What dimensions would such a box need to be able to hold 20 arrows?**

I am specifically asking for the dimensions of a box that can hold 20 arrows because that determines how many boxes I can put in a bag of holding, which will equal how many arrows I can ***safely*** put in a bag of holding.

Answer (score 8):

## RAW:

Quiver holds 20 arrows and weighs 1 pound, and 20 arrows weigh 1 pound. (PHB p.152-153)

Bag of Holding:

> The bag can hold up to 500 pounds, not exceeding a volume of 64 cubic feet. (DMG p.153)

By weight, this gives us an absolute maximum of 250 loaded quivers.

## Dimensions are not given by RAW:

But if we look at typical arrows. They are 30-32 inches in length with fletchings that are about 3/8 of an inch tall. If we allow a little extra space for manipulating the arrows, we get a case/quiver that is 2x10x36 inches; or 3/7 of a cubic foot.

### By volume with the assumed dimensions, we can fit 149 loaded quivers in the  Bag of Holding

Note: There are many different styles of quivers. It is possible to have a capped quiver that protects the arrows and allows access by simply removing the cap.